# Ratings google results page - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, woocommerce, rating

I have a really specific question I coudn't figured out.
I'm using wordpress with woocommerce review.
I would like the rating to appear on google with the name of my website such as
"Rating: 5 - Review by guideliterie"
instead of
"Rating: 5 · ‎1 review "

Here is what is display for a product on my website :
[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=guideliterie%20emma%20matrelat%20hybride&rlz=1C5CHFA_enDE906DE906&oq=guideliterie%20emma%20matrelat%20hybride&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.7083j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Here is my competitors, ans how I would like it to appear :
[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=avis%20matelas%20emma%20original&oq=avis%20matelas%20emma%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l5j69i60l2.7031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Should you need any forther info I would be happy to give it to you.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use https://search.google.com/test/rich-results to test competitor and your results and fix if there are any errors. Keep in mind google not always will use them or on specific device or search word etc. There is no guarantee google will do it and also needs time your website to be more trusted by the engine. I have recepie project and everything is 100% as it should but not all recepies have image on results and cant do sh*t just waiting :)

Comment: @MartinMirchev Thanks a lot for your answer.  It does not directly answer my question since the rating is indeed showing but I would like the name of the rater instead of "1rating" and im not sure if I have to do something about it myself or not. Thanks for the usefull link gonna check it out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.